# pexpect "no such file or directory" for a bash command that works

Tags: python, bash, grep, pexpect

```
sCMD = 'ssh user@host cat some/path | grep "Oct 31\|Oct 30"'
child = pexpect.spawn(sCMD)
try:
    child.expect("assword")
except pexpect.EOF:
    raise Exception("Cannot connect to host")
child.sendline(ssh_pass)
lData = [s.strip(' \n\r:') for s in child.readlines()]
```

lData[0] reads "No such file or directory"

if I change the first line to read:

```
sCMD = 'ssh user@host cat some/path'
```

Then lData contains all the lines from the file.

But if I execute the exact same command (with the grep) in a terminal it works fine - it returns the text I expect. No complaints.

Any idea why the command performs differently when executed via pexpect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sCMD = 'ssh user@host \'cat some/path | grep "Oct 31\|Oct 30"\''
```

for some reason pexpect requires those extra single quotes.

Comment: The difference is seen when you run `print sCMD`. In the first case, you are piping the output of ssh to grep, in the other, you are running a `cat | grep` pipeline over ssh. Nothing to do with pexcept

Comment: Because then the `grep`, too, runs on the remote host. You were attempting to run the pipeline locally, which doesn't work in this context.

Comment: You should fix the [useless use of `cat`:](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html) `sCMD = 'ssh user@host grep "Oct 31\|Oct 30" some/path'`

Comment: Or `grep "Oct 3[01]"` for that matter.